# Rails, uninitialized constant Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder in sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails, faraday

I'm using rails 4 and sunspot solr, when I pass the params to the controller for performing the search, i'm getting **uninitialized constant Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder** error

I followed the steps under https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot

My model looks as follow,

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  searchable do
     text :title, :description
  end
end
```

and my controller action is **blogs_controllers.rb**

```
def index
  @search = Post.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @results = @search.results
end
```

and the form is as follow,

```
<form action="<%= posts_search_path %>" method="GET" role="Search">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search by post title" required="required">
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>
```

not sure why this error is occuring.

Comment: Share the exact error from console and backtrace

Comment: Did you restarted rails server after installing gem or after bundling?

Comment: yes i did restarted the rails server as well as the sunspot_solr server, even though the problem remains, @Aashish

Comment: SOLR Request (38.5ms)  [ path=select parameters={fq: ["type:Post"], q: "stone", fl: "* score", qf: "title_text description_text", defType: "edismax", start: 0, rows: 30} ]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 127ms

NameError - uninitialized constant Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder:  @Md. Farhan Memon

Answer (score 0):

Use of `Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder` in rsolr was [added in version 2.0.0](https://github.com/rsolr/rsolr/commit/65017d8e608d8690c5061a28ecae2c3a93d39e90). `Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder` was [added to faraday in version 0.9.0](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/commit/ab2a85565808e33ed31e981feb5f197c6a37dda6). [rsolr does not specify a minimum version of faraday](https://github.com/rsolr/rsolr/blob/c0425183d34edf31db25b80ce670797cd58e950f/rsolr.gemspec#L37). I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/rsolr/rsolr/pull/189) to fix this.

Either upgrade faraday to 0.9.0 or above, or downgrade rsolr to a version before 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Install `gem 'faraday'` and run `bundle install` this should resolve the problem.